# Ajax extend not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari

I found issue in the below code snippet used in jquery.dataTables.js this issue only exists in safari browser.

```
  oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax($.extend(baseAjax, {
                url: ajax || oSettings.sAjaxSource
            }));
```

I am getting TypeError: Type error.

Comment: Why are you trying to do a boolean bitwise operator (||) on a string? If you're trying to emulate an IF statement it won't work (if ajax is not defined then use oSettings.sAjaxSource). SO use a proper if-then construction; it's clearer for someone else to read your code too

Comment: @Pianoman - the `||` will work just fine.  It's equivalent to `url: ajax ? ajax : oSettings.sAjaxSource` and is a very common shortcut nomenclature in Javascript.

Comment: Do you know which piece of code is causing the `TypeError`?  Is it the `oSettings.jqXHR`?  or the `$.extend()` function call?  or the `oSettings.sAjaxSource` reference?  I think you should do `console.log()` statements or a debugger breakpoint to see what `oSettings` and `baseAjax` are to make sure they are objects that can be used as expected.  If either of them is undefined, that could be the cause of the error and that would guide you as to where to look next.

Comment: We debugged the jquery datables plugin via safari browser & found the ajax function giving us an error.
 
For $.ajax function ,first parameter is object while the second parameter is url.

Comment: @jfriend00 ah, thanx. learned something myself then!